# Traffic Routing in HERE SDK

Tags: here-api

I am using the following code to create a route using the Premium Android SDK:

```
RouteOptions ro = new RouteOptions();
ro.setTransportMode(RouteOptions.TransportMode.CAR);
ro.setRouteType(RouteOptions.Type.BALANCED);
ro.setRouteCount(1);


RoutePlan rp = new RoutePlan();
// start route on current position
rp.setRouteOptions(ro);
rp.addWaypoint(new RouteWaypoint(currentGeoCoordinate));
rp.addWaypoint(new RouteWaypoint(stopGeoCordinate));

DynamicPenalty dp = new DynamicPenalty();
dp.setTrafficPenaltyMode(TrafficPenaltyMode.OPTIMAL);
stopGeoCordinate = new GeoCoordinate(trip.getLatitude(), trip.getLongitude());


CoreRouter rm = new CoreRouter();
rm.setDynamicPenalty(dp);

rm.calculateRoute(rp, new CoreRouter.Listener() { ...
```

Using the Android Studio Network Profiler I have seen this single request result in about 30 of the same backend API calls to the following URL:

https://v154-105-30-8.route.hybrid.api.here.com/rt?.....

Is this the expected behavior so that a single traffic routing request results in 30 transactions, or am I doing something fundamentally incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up, the SDK team acknowledged there is a bug with SDK 3.14 (and possibly earlier).

When the NavigationManager is set to DYNAMIC traffic routing, if the route would go slightly off the path, it would immediately call the server for rerouting.  In the example I created, a .5 mile trip resulted in 70 calls to the Server Routing API.

The SDK team stated this should only occur after 5 seconds but was not working properly.  3.15 should address this issue.

So, if anyone is using 3.14 (I am unsure about earlier versions) with the NavigationManager and DYNAMIC routing, check your transaction count as it may be much higher then expected.